# How to make a messaging layout

Tags: java, android, layout

I am looking to make something really similar to this:

[image: Message like layout I want]
<sub>(source: [iphonehacks.com](http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ios-7-delete-messages.jpg))</sub>

I want to know what to use (GridView, ListView) and how to detect if message from sender or reciever, and yes I know its a iPhone layout but I like it the most. Please let me know what I need to use and other information maybe a link!

Thanks
Fusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Up for the layout use [9 Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images. Create two 9patch images for sent message and received message.

Check if the message is sent by the user. Use a boolean variable set it to false if the message is received when you look for the messages. else it will be true. Use layoutparams, view holder and place the messages accordingly.

```
ViewHolder holder; 
holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());

LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();

    if(message.isMine())
    {
        holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.left_grey);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    }
    else
    {
        holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right_blue);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    }
```

//right_blue & left_grey will be your 9 patch images respectively

This [Link](http://blog.booleanbites.com/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html) has a very good example.
And [Github source](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Android-Speech-Bubble) for the same.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Its ListView with vertical orientation. You have to know about Adapter, ListView and how connect them. Some tutor:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I've already been through that but it doesn't actually hit my question on the head, I mean to look for something that is a little more indepth with my specific question.